# Slow ArcMap Start up

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap

My ArcMap take about 3-4 minutes to start. It was good before with less than 10-20 sec start time. I have Dell Precision 6500 Laptop with 16 GB Ram with i7 processor. I could not figure out what is making it late? Can anybody help or had similar problem solved?

Comment: look through your folder connections, there may be some unreferenced/invalid paths. On startup Catalog checks these paths and if they're invalid it will 'time out' what you're experiencing is probably multiple 'time out' periods on start-up. If there are invalid folder connections remove them in ArcCatalog: right click on the connection and select 'Disconnect folder'.

Comment: This can also sometimes be seen when you have 3rd party (non-ESRI) extensions/plug-ins/tools installed as some of those perform their own start-up operations that can take a while or have issues that cause similar time out issues within that tool.

Comment: The next step is to look at your Ad-ins directory(s) and make sure they all exist. If you're on a notebook consider copying add-ins to a local directory rather than relying on a network.

Answer (score 2):

The standard ESRI tech support response probably would be to reset your application profile.  They usually recommend renaming the ESRI folder in your user application data folder.  That is effective in letting you know if the problem is in your templates or registry settings, but you do lose all customizations.  So if it works and you don't want to redo your customizations you might delete the new ESRI folder, rename the renamed ESRI folder back and then try to hunt down a particular problem template or setting.  See http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/90079-Resetting-your-ArcGIS-application-profile.

In the future you might consider making your ArcMap template read only, or make a copy of a good one to replace it, since every time you and close it the template gets rewritten and after a while it can get cranky.

Comment: Yep. When this happened to me, deleting `Normal.mxt` brought things back to life. And as @johns notes, you'll lose all your settings, like where you have your toolbars arranged, etc.